# Using the DecimalFormat method

Tags: java, function, methods, decimalformat

1. Display `y` to three decimal places
2. Display how many digits come before the decimal point and how many comes after a    number. On `x`, `y` and `z`
3. Create a string `E` that consists of `D` in reverse concatenated with `F`, including a space between them
4. Search for the substring `‘i’` in `c` and replace it for `‘fff’`

> x = 123.456, y = 54/5, z = √2, D = “Decimal”, F = “Function”

I did this for question 1 and it works but I am not sure if this is how I am suppose to do this and I have not clue how to go about doing question 2,3 and 4. Any help would be appreciated.

```
double y = 54.0/5.0;
DecimalFormat y_format = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); 
String formatted_string1 = y_format.format(y);
System.out.println(formatted_string1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2, you can divide the number by 10 until it reaches 0. A simple counter with a while loop would work well. You could so similar for the other case. (using multiplication)

For 3, Simply use a loop to read a character at a time from D and concatenate to a new String.

```
for ( i from D.length to 0)
  newString += D.charAt(i)
newString += F
```

For 4, check the [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method in String.